# Java String manipulation based on most frequent char count

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

In recent interview, I was asked to find solution for below String manipulation program. 
***Given a string s, represent the most frequent character with 1, the 2nd most frequent character with 01, third with 001 etc.***

> ### if String is "marrymyyyr", then output should be :
>
> char count for each character is m:2 , a:1, r:3, y:4  highest count
>   number is 4 so the character with that count should be printed 1
>   inplace of that char, char with count 3 should be printed as 01
>   inplace of that char and so on.
>
> ### Output : 001(m)0001(a)01(r)01(r)1(y)001(m)1(y)1(y)1(y)01(r)

I used HashMap to keep track of count for each character. then I was unable to solve the problem. I know I have to implement some mechanism to apply hashing/mapping to hashmap based on most frequent char mapped with its correspondence resultant string with combination of"1" "0" and print char with mapped resultant string instead of that char.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you used `HashMap`. If you created the map as `Map<Character, AtomicInteger>`, then you can update the value directly, without affecting the map.

This improves performance of the counting step of the process, but also allows you to then replace the "count" value with a value representing the number of 0's to print for a character, aka a "rank".

Example: With the counts being `m:2, a:1, r:3, y:4` (from question), you would sort the list descending (`y:4, r:3, m:2, a:1`), then replace the counts with incrementing ranks: `y:0, r:1, m:2, a:3`.

If you use a `LinkedHashMap`, then multiple characters with equal count would be ranked in order of first appearance.

With those ranks, you can now convert the input. *(The following is for any Java version. On Java 8, lambdas would reduce the code a lot. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.)*

```
private static String test(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

    // Collect chars with count of occurrences
    Map<Character, AtomicInteger> charMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Character c : chars) {
        AtomicInteger count = charMap.get(c);
        if (count == null)
            charMap.put(c, new AtomicInteger(1));
        else
            count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    // Sort char/count pairs by count (descending)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>[] charArr = charMap.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[charMap.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(charArr, new Comparator<Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> e1, Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> e2) {
            return Integer.compare(e2.getValue().intValue(), e1.getValue().intValue()); // descending
        }
    });

    // Replace "count" with "rank" (this updates values in charMap)
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++)
        charArr[i].getValue().set(i);

    // Generate result
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c : chars) {
        int rank = charMap.get(c).intValue();
        while (rank-- > 0)
            buf.append('0');
        buf.append('1');
        buf.append('(').append(c).append(')'); // Remove?
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Test**

```
System.out.println(test("marrymyyyr"));
```

**Output**

```
001(m)0001(a)01(r)01(r)1(y)001(m)1(y)1(y)1(y)01(r)
```

The phrasing of the question makes it sound like the letters should be *replaced* ("inplace of"). If so, comment out or delete the line marked with `// Remove?`

**Output**

```
00100010101100111101
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what exactly I was looking for. I haven't used Atomic Integer before. Can you explain why we can't use Integer and need to use Atomic Integer?

Comment: @Mausam `Integer` is immutable, `AtomicInteger` can be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I learned one new data type other than normal Integer. I really appreciate your step by step solution with explanation.